# To display Rupees in words in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to display rupess in words in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Example: if the amount is 1000, it has to display as "one thousand"

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the Humanizr lib for .NET (https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer)
With that you can do something like:

```
1000.ToWords() => "one thousand"
```